# CodedUI Telerik Tab

Tags: telerik, silverlight-5.0, coded-ui-tests

I'm experiencing issues with CodedUI for the telerik control for Tabs in Silverlight. I can record what I do within a tab using the CodedUI, but when I come to executing the CodedUI Test its unable to pick out the controls within the telerik Tab Control container.

Basically what I have is a a Textbox within the telerik Tab Container. And I've tried to add in text inside the textbox as a CodedUI Test.

I'm not sure if there is a work around here. I had made a quick Visual Studio Solution that replicates the problem I'm experiencing. And I'm using telerik Silverlight controls version 2012.2.725.1050.

Here is the exception Message

```
"BasicMessage=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties."
```

I can include the stack trace upon request and even the VS Solution if required.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used silverlight but I find the same thing happens with Telerik for Windows Forms using c#.

I do the following to avoid getting that error:

There should be a "EnableCodedUITests" property for the control in the properties.

This should be set to true if it does exist. Rinse and repeat for all controls that have that property and you should pass the tests.